# Unexpected behaviour when updating a 3D array

Tags: python, iteration

In reality, the problem is that I'm trying to take a list of atom positions in a unit cell and construct a corresponding super-cell, given an input of how many times to repeat the cell in each direction.

This results in a loop structure:

```
#Create Every Unit Cell in SuperCell
aNum=2
bNum=2
cNum=2
atomPos = copy.deepcopy(atomPositions)
for l in range(len(atomPos)):
    index=0
    for i in range(cNum):
        for j in range(bNum):
            for k in range(aNum):
                for _ in range(numEachAtom[l]):
                    atomPositions[l][index][0] = atomPos[l][index][0] + 1*k
                    atomPositions[l][index][1] = atomPos[l][index][1] + 1*j
                    atomPositions[l][index][2] = atomPos[l][index][2] + 1*i
                    print atomPositions[0][0]
                    index += 1
```

Where `atomPositions` is a 3D array such that: 
`atomPositions[atomtype=l][atom=index][atomposition=0] = [x,y,z]` and the print statement is for diagnostic purposes.

The problem is that from the print statement it seems that `atomPositions[0][0]` changes more often than the atom type and as index seems to be updating correctly, I simply don't understand this.

Why does `atomPositions[0][0]` change more often than `l`?

Originally I came across the problem of modifying a list that you're iterating over, hence the deep copy at the start. Any comments would be much appreciated!

P.S. This is my first time asking a question and I'm a complete beginner in Python, so please feel free to comment on my lack of formatting/clarity/style etc.

**Edit:**
An example of the beginning of the output for `numEachAtom=[4,6]`:

```
[0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[1.1761125167550424, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[1.1761125167550424, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[1.1761125167550424, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[1.1761125167550424, 0.17611251675504244, 0.17611251675504244]
[0.17611251675504244, 1.1761125167550424, 0.17611251675504244]
[0.17611251675504244, 1.1761125167550424, 0.17611251675504244]
[0.17611251675504244, 1.1761125167550424, 0.17611251675504244]
```

etc.

**Edit:** How atomPositions is initialised:

```
#Separate out positions of different atom types
atomPositions = []
counter=0
for i,atomN in enumerate(numEachAtom):         
    atomPositions.append( origAtomPositions[counter:counter+atomN] )
    counter += atomN
```

**Edit:** Dependencies etc

```
import sys
import scipy as sp
from scipy import * 
import copy
```

**Edit:** atomPositions[0] is initialised as

```
[[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]
[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]
[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]
[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]
[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]
[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]
[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]
[ 0.17611252  0.17611252  0.17611252]
[ 0.32388748  0.32388748  0.32388748]
[ 0.42611252  0.42611252  0.42611252]
[ 0.07388748  0.07388748  0.07388748]]
```

Comment: Hey, this is a pretty good question! It might be helpful to provide a short example of the output, so that people can see what your problem is in a concrete way.

Comment: How do you initialize `atomPositions`?

Comment: Can you provide a working example for the contents of the lists?

Comment: If you're doing lots of numeric stuff on arrays, consider learning [Numpy](http://numpy.scipy.org/).

Comment: @Marcin, I've updated the question based on your comments. I have to say I'm impressed at how quickly people have answered. I'm now quite sure how commenting is supposed to work, so again please feel free to correct any abuses I make etc.

Comment: @JensTimmerman And again

Comment: @TCTopCat People love questions which are well-asked. This could be an effect of the data that you have in atompos. It might be better to step through this with a debugger to see what is happening, or print out the bits of your data to see what is driving this.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks very much again for your input, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'by an effect of the data', could you expand on this please? I've printed out all the relevant(and some not so relevant) variables I can think of such as i,j,k,l,index etc. and so far I have only proven myself right, unfortunately D. Knuth was right and it hasn't been enough! :-)

Comment: @TCTopCat I mean that it could be artifact of patterns in your input data. You may find it instructive to step through this code in a debugger just to see what is happening.

Comment: @TCTopCat since this is Python 2.X (you can tell by the print statements), consider using `xrange` over `range` as the former simply constructs an iterator rather than the whole list each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very much as if you have somewhere multiplied your input list.  As this is a nested list it won't do what you want.

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't see this, but I found the culprit. As a matter of note though, I find this behaviour quite counter-intuitive. Thank you everyone who spent time on this.
      `#Expand for Extra Atoms
    for i in range(len(atomPositions)):
        atomPositions[i] *= aNumber*bNumber*cNumber`

Comment: I assumed there must be something happening outside the posted code as nothing in it would produce the behaviour you were reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using both `itertools` and `numpy` here, two very helpful libraries you should become acquainted with. The question:

> take a list of atom positions in a unit cell and construct a corresponding super-cell, given an input of how many times to repeat the cell in each direction.

Is answered below, in a general way for any dimension. For illustrative purposes I use a 2D array, but it will work fine if you pass it a 3D array. The quad loop you use in your post is replaced with a single loop over all the possible cell directions with `product`. Take it apart and play with it to see how it works.

```
from numpy import *
from itertools import product

# Pass in the points, plus a vector that indicates the repeats in each direction
def supercell(R, v):
    v    = array(v) + 1
    n,d  = R.shape

    # Construct the copy directions
    CV  = list(product(*map(range,v)))
    R2  = zeros((len(CV)*n,d))

    for i,cell in enumerate(CV):
        R2[i*n:(i+1)*n,:] = cell+R
    return R2

# Construct some random points within a unit cell to work with
N,dimension = 100, 2
# Contrain them so you can see the supercell
R = random.random((N,dimension))*.6 + .5

R2 = supercell(R,[2,3])

# Plot the results
from pylab import *
scatter(*zip(*R2),color='b')
scatter(*zip(*R),color='r')
show()
```

[image]

In your example, with a copy of 2 in each positive direction, the vector `CV` would look like:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

this is the magic of the `product` function.

Comment: Thanks very much, that should be very useful. I'll definitely have a play with that later. If you've got any ideas though, I'd appreciate any comments about why the code posted in the question acts so strangely?

Comment: @TCTopCat I tried at first, but I don't see why you need three separate indices. What I see starting from the inner most: (x,y,z) demarcation then the atom's index. The outer most index makes no sense. In the example above, my supercell has shape `(N,3)` where `N` is the new number of atoms. Your examples have `(x,N,3)`. What is `x`?

Comment: The first index of atomicPositions refers to the type of atom. Its a little convoluted, but for the purposes of my input files (to a Density Functional Theory simulation package called [VASP](http://www.vasp.at/)) I need to make this separation to ensure that the new atomic positions are written to file in groups of the same element.

Answer (score 0):

`atomPositions[0][0]` will change a couple of times, that's what your `for _ in range(numEachAtom[l])` does.

What is this loop for anyway? Can't you just write

```
#Create Every Unit Cell in SuperCell
aNum=2
bNum=2
cNum=2
atomPos = copy.deepcopy(atomPositions)
for l in range(len(atomPos)):
    index=0
    for i in range(cNum):
        for j in range(bNum):
            for k in range(aNum):
                atomPositions[l][index][0] = atomPos[l][index][0] + numEachAtom[l]*k
                atomPositions[l][index][1] = atomPos[l][index][1] + numEachAtom[l]*j
                atomPositions[l][index][2] = atomPos[l][index][2] + numEachAtom[l]*i
                print atomPositions[0][0]
```

Edit: op just updated his code where he inserted the index in the loop, so this doesn't make sense anymore.